# Utility premium

Tags: probability, utility, risk-assessment

For the customer, the utility premium $H^{\star}$ is defined as the premium making the homeowner indifferent to insure or not, e.g. $H^{\star}$ solves
$$u(x-H^{\star})=\mathbb{E}u(x-X).$$

How does it look for the insurer (insurance company)? Is it just that the insurance company offers insurance if $H>\mathbb{E}[X]$? Or how does one calculate the utility premium for the insurer?

Comment: Well in theory, if the insurer charges a premium that is greater than this $H^\star$ to this customer, then the customer would prefer no insurance. So the significance of $H^\star$ for the insurer would be that it represents the largest premium that they can charge to this customer (and still get the customer to join).

Comment: The insurer invests the premium until it is necessary to pay out. The utility to the insurer is the return on that investment. So to calculate the utility premium for the insurer, you must allow know what ROI the insurer earns.